Absence of length contraction for a translating rod in one dimension
I was reading Section 2 of Einstein's paper, and began thinking about the idea of a rod translating with a horizontal velocity $v$. The rod has two ends, end A and end B. If the rod is translating with a velocity $v$ in the horizontal direction, end A and end B are translating with velocity $v$ too. In other words, a rod is moving in the horizontal direction, and an observer in a stationary frame watches the rod, where both ends of the rod move the same amount during a specific time interval. Therefore, for the case of a translating rod, the rod remains the same length and there is no length contraction. I have seen a rather popular textbook on Modern Physics discuss length contraction for this physical situation, which seems very incorrect to me, so I just want to make sure I'm not missing something. There is no length contraction in this simple case, right?

It is very unclear what you mean. The fact that "both ends of the rod move the same amount during a specific time interval" does not imply that there is no length contraction.

Dale (below) has clarified my confusion. The moving rod as viewed from the stationary frame starts out with a different length and maintains that length throughout. I was incorrectly assuming that both coordinate systems agreed upon the rod's length at the initial time.

No. In that simple case there is length contraction.
You are correct that in both frames the left end and the right end travel at the same speed. You are also correct that this fact implies that in each frame the length is constant over time.
However, it does not imply that the two frames agree in the length. In fact, length contraction is the fact that the two frames disagree about the length. Not that the length changes over time in either frame.

Thanks. I was interpreting the initial condition incorrectly. The moving coordinate system does not suddenly accelerate from zero velocity to a nonzero velocity. Rather, the moving coordinate system is always moving. The option for length contraction is open.

Why move the rod? It is conceptually easier to move the observer. Of course, the cases are equivalent in physics, but as far as understanding relativity: they are not equivalent because of misunderstanding.
Many times on this site I have posted my rules-for-relativity, which have been developed over years or answering questions on....wait for it...:https://physics.stackexchange.com
The rules are not necessarily ordered, but they are:
Work in well defined reference frames. Start with the "at rest frame" and go in order. That is:
"Alice" is in $S$, at rest in the natural frame of the question.
"Bob" is moving at $\beta$, and is in $S'$.
Charlie and David are hopefully not needed.
Note the pattern: A, B, C, D...don't use A, B, C, D for anything else...like the ends of a rod.
No, only label EVENTS, which are points in spacetime.
Events in $S^{\alpha}$ are labeled as:
$$ E_i = (t_i^{(\alpha)}, x_i^{(\alpha)})^{(\alpha)} $$
where $t$ and $x$ refer to time and position. If we need more spatial dimensions, then $z$ is direction of motion and $x$ defines transverse. If we need $y$, then it is the azimuthal lab variable...aka OOPs (out-of-plane...we only need this for the decay of vector mesons, so fuggetaboutit).
We can compute events in various coordinates via Lorentz Transforms, if we make the origins of $S$, $S'$, $\cdots$, equal. We need to do that, at all costs.
So, here is your problem:
Alice in $S$ has a rod at rest that she wants to measure. It has a back (front) end on the world line:
$$ W_-(t) = (t, 0) $$
$$ W_+(t) = (t, L) $$
She measures it's length at $t=0$, which gives her two events:
$$ E_- = (0, 0) $$
$$ E_+ = (0, L) $$
The length of the rod, $L_0$, is the spatial difference of its endpoints at the same time:
$$ L_0 = |t_+ - t_-| = |L-0| = |L| = L $$
which we call the proper length.
Bob is moving in $S'$ at $\beta$ along the $x$-axis (note: $c=1$).
Bob looks at Alice's measurements and sees that:
$$ E_- = (0, 0)' $$
$$ E_+ = \Big(\gamma(t_+-\beta x_+)',
\gamma(x_+-\beta t_+)\Big) $$
$$ E_+ = \Big(\gamma(0-\beta L), \gamma(L-0\beta)\Big) $$
$$E_+ = (-\gamma\beta L, \gamma L) $$
which means Alice's data are useless because the measurements of the endpoints were not simultaneous.
(Note that the prime on the coordinates indicate that they are $S'$..the prime is not on the event because events don't have an inherent coordinate system).
For his length measurement, he can keep the 1st event, $E_-$, but he needs a 3rd event, $E'_+$ that occurs at $t'=0$.
That event is:
$$ E'_+ = (0, L/\gamma)' $$
which I state without proof. Draw a Minkowski diagram and convince yourself it is correct.
For Bob, the length of the rod is:
$$ L'=|(E'_+)_x - (E_-)_x| = |L/\gamma - 0| = L_0/\gamma $$
The rod is length contracted.

Thank you for the event-based perspective!
